# Minimum distance for tangential contact between two cones.

Tags: geometry

This problem relates to a construction that was done using a 3d graphics software. But I am seeking to describe and understand it in a mathematically rigorous way. There are probably some ambiguities that might have crept in while framing this question.

There are two congruent cones $C_1$ and $C_2$ with the same half vertical angle(or opening angle/aperture) $\alpha$ and slant height $l$. The vertices of the two cones $O_1$ and $O_2$ are at diagonally opposite ends of a rectangle (or maybe a parallelogram) with the bases of the cones facing each other. The plane on which the two cones rest essentially is a tangent plane to the cone that is tangential along the ruling(generatrix)  $O_1A_1$ on $C_1$ and $O_2A_2$ on $C_2$ respectively. I am trying to work out what must be the minimum distance between the vertices of the two cones that would ensure tangential contact between them at one single point only.

This distance essentially corresponds to the length of the diagonal $O_1O_2$ of the parallelogram $O_1A_1O_2A_2$. The second diagonal is $A_1A_2$. It appears to me that projecting the tangential point of contact onto the plane on which the cones rest will correspond to the centroid of the parallelogram, i.e. the intersection point of these diagonals. But I am not sure how to prove this either.

I have attached a screenshot of the construction as seen from bottom view.[image]

I believe that the slant height $l$ of the cone might need to be increased for the contact to be possible which is fine as this just amounts to scaling and does not change the angle $\alpha$. Any ideas on how to approach this question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I interpret your question correctly, you can get started using these general principles.

(i) At the unknown point of contact $C$ the tangent plane to the cone through $C$ contains the vertex $V$ of the cone;

(ii) the *unit* normal vector $N$ to the tangent plane to the conical surface  at $C$ must pass  through  a point $P$ located on the central axis of that cone. Let $A$ denote a *unit* vector directed along that axis. The (signed). aperture angle satisfies $N\cdot A = \sin \alpha$.

In particular, in the case that both cones have the same absolute aperture angle,  $ \sin \alpha_1=A_1\cdot N= A_2\cdot(- N) =\sin \alpha_2$, so $ N\cdot (A_2+A_1)=0$. (This corrects a sig error in a former version of this answer.)

Next, by (i), we also know $ V_1- V_2$ lies in the common tangent plane, so $ N\cdot (V_2- V_1)=0$.

Together these two orthogonality conditions imply that $N$ must be parallel to the vector cross product $ (V_2- V_1)\times (A_2+ A_1)$. This determines $N$ explicitly.

You can visualize the situation as follows. Treat $N$ as the vertical direction. Consider the common tangent plane as the clear glass top of a horizontal table. You have one cone resting on the upper surface of the glass, and a second cone resting on the lower surface of the glass. Each cone intersects the glass in a ray extending from the vertex of that cone (a generator of that cone). (You want to find where those two generators intersect). If you draw instead a parametrized ray from  the vertex $V$ directed along the axial vector $A$ by setting $P(t)= V+tA$, its  perpendicular projection onto the tabletop will trace out the generator on that cone. (This is true for both cones).

A quick way to obtain such  projections is to simply cross $ P(t)\times N$. This wipes out the component of $P(t)$ that is parallel to $N$ and *rotates the component that is perpendicular to $N$* by 90 degrees. So you get a 90-degree rotated version of the ray in the table top by this method. You can compensate for the 90 degree twist by performing another cross product with $N$. This cross-product trick works on both cones, and gives you a congruent configuration of two planar generators whose intersection is sought.

Thus the problem is reduced to finding the intersection of two parametrized lines in a plane.

Your specific problem might just reduce to the following.
Draw the table-top diagram and look at how close the vertices must be in order for the two generators to intersect in the configuration you seek (by making the slant heights long enough).

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I will try out what you suggested. One thing I also noticed is that if tangential contact is achieved, then the the point of contact and the two vertices of the cone form an isoceles triangle in the common tangent plane at the point of contact.